# みんなの日本語って教科書**が**だれでも知っているね。it should be を not が right?

Tags: particles

みんなの日本語って教科書**が**だれでも知っているね。it should be を not が right?
知っている is transitive verb.
same phenomenon in トムさん、さっき山田さんって人**が**探してたよ。

Answer (score 1):

If you really copied this sentence correctly, this が is intended to be an **exhaustive-listing が**. That is, the speaker introduced みんなの日本語 as *the* only textbook everyone knows.

> みんなの日本語って教科書**が**だれでも知っているね。
> The textbook called *Minna-no Nihongo*, it's the (only) one everyone knows.

The sentence above is not incorrect, but it would be more natural if a relative clause were used:

> みんなの日本語って教科書**が**だれでも知っているものだね。
> The textbook called *Minna-no Nihongo* is the one everyone knows.

If this implication of ("the only") is unnecessary (which usually is), you can use は or を instead (は is usually preferred).

> みんなの日本語って教科書**は**だれでも知っているね。
> みんなの日本語って教科書**を**だれでも知っているね。
> Everyone knows a textbook called *Minna-no Nihongo*. / One textbook everyone knows is *Minna-no Nihongo*.

See Also:

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)

  > Exhaustive-listing works similar to contrastive は, implying contrast to the rest of the universe of discourse. A:「だれが日本語を知っていますか？」 B:「ジョンが日本語できます」 できる is a non-action verb, so this is exhaustive-listing. Assume that we are talking about the three new students: Jon, Bill and Tom. **If B knows that Jon and Tom can both speak Japanese, B just lied. If B knows Jon can speak Japanese, but doesn't know about the others, the contrastive は is appropriate to use instead of が**.
- [Is the object uniquely determined when using は in the following sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35966/5010)

Comment: I think the most notable thing here is that 知る (a supposedly transitive verb) is accepting が at all. Would you say there are other cases it does work, or maybe more importantly, doesn’t work?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie 知る doesn't take が, but the sentence can be understood as two sentences ("It's the textbook called みんなの日本語; it's the one everyone knows") or as a slightly broken sentence with ものだ omitted.  It's tricky but I cannot say it's incorrect... Example: 「部屋に誰がいましたか？」「彼が、私見てました。」

Comment: @naruto ね at the end of the sentence means 'right?' ,right?
you didn't insert it in your translation i think. was there a reason for that?

Answer (score -2):

I am not following this sentence.

The は is attached to みんなの日本語(は)...

Is this sentence from somewhere?
Perhaps the sentence may be re-worded as,
皆の日本語って、誰でも知っているような、教科書からきた感じだ。

I suppose the lesson here is that って　after the subject acts as は